# SVG Element CSS change not visible in Chrome 35 - 36

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, svg, google-chrome-devtools

I have an application with a bunch of SVG elements. When I hover on the SVG elements, they temporarily change color and if I click one, it changes color permanently (or until it is clicked again). 
When the SVG element is clicked, this code is called:

```
styles = styles + " selected";
$(this).attr("class", styles);
```

CSS rule fills the SVG element with color. This worked in all browsers for some time, but has stopped working in Chrome 35 and problem persists in 36 beta. It seems to be fixed in 37. 
In Chrome, the GUI seems to be stuck - the hover and click actions work, but the color changes aren't visible - the code is executed correctly, but it seems it is not rendered properly.

I have several insights:

1. This happens for the first time I do that - when I navigate somewhere else in the application and go back (it shows the SVGs again), it starts working.
2. When I inspect the code in Dev tools, I see the element has the "selected" class and also, the element has the colored fill (in CSS inspector) - but it is not visible to the user. When I disable and enable any CSS rule in the CSS inspector, it starts working.
   I researched Chrome's changelogs, but can't find anything relevant. It works fine in all other major browsers.

EDIT: no matter the way I add the rule to the element, it won't render it until I reload the whole parent element, which I cannot do.
The code seems to do exactly what I want (internally), but Chrome just won't show the change.
Is there some way to simulate the same action as Google dev tools css rule change ? (Which always fixes it for me) ?

Kind regards,
Lukas

Comment: Hi Robert, the question is - why isn't it filling properly like in other browsers or Chrome versions and how can I force it to behave the way I want?

Comment: Presumably it's a bug. And as you've already discovered, you could delete and recreate the CSS rule to work around it.

Comment: Even if I try to disable and re-enable the rule from within js like this: $(this).css("fill",""); $(this).css("fill","#02B2B0"); it doesn't work. Is this what you meant ?

Comment: No that's not what I meant. I meant delete the rule itself and recreate it not recreate your assignment of the element to the rule.

Comment: Robert, thank you for trying to help me. I do not understand how I should do it though. The css rule is defined in a .css file and works properly. How do I simulate the same behavior as in Chrome developer tools - the disabling and enabling the rule ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the CSS rules for a web page you can get to them via

```
document.styleSheets
```

so the first stylesheet would be

```
document.styleSheets[0]
```

So if you had

```
p {
    color: blue;
}
```

in the only stylesheet for the page then

```
var rule = document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0]
```

and

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.setProperty('color','#00cc00',null);
```

would update the color property in the rule. There's more information [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html).

Comment: I parsed the styleSheet, deleted the rule and re-inserted it again and it seems to be fixed so far. Note: any change in the stylesheet seems to do the trick. Thank you very much Robert.